# Why aren't all calendars showing up in reminders

Tags: macos, ical, calendar, reminders

When I create a reminder in iCal on Mac OS 10.7 and try to assign a calendar to it then not all calendars seem show up.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from OSX 10.7 there are 2 kinds of calendars: Calendars and Reminder Lists. Make sure the calendar you're trying to assign is a Reminder List.